# middle ware is not working, in spite of giving next statement

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to create 2 middlewares .
but node is not moving beyond the first middle ware . I have given next() also in both.
Please point me to the mistake.
here is is the code

app.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('./log-winston');
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const middle = require ('./api/middle/middlewares');
const registerRoutes = require('./api/routes/register')
const morgan = require('morgan');

app.use(morgan(middle.logFunction));
app.use(morgan(middle.logFunction, { stream: middle.accessLogStream }));


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// These 2 are custom Middlewares, Code is not moving beyond the first one

app.use(middle.winstonLogger());
app.use(middle.showMachineId());

console.log("DEBUG");
app.use('/register', registerRoutes);


module.exports = app;
```

middlewares.js :

```
exports.winstonLogger = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("This is winston Logger")
    next()
};

exports.showMachineId = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("This is Machine ID")
    next()
};
```

The result is :

```
[nodemon] starting `node .\server.js`
This is winston Logger
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

It is not printing second Middleware "showMachineId" and "DEBUG" in app.js.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
app.use(middle.winstonLogger());
```

to this:

```
app.use(middle.winstonLogger);
```

The first calls the function immediately and passes its non-existent return value to `app.use()`.  When you put `()` at the end of a function that calls it immediately.  That's not what you want here.  The code doesn't move past this because calling it immediately calls it with no arguments and you then try to call `next()` which will `throw` because `next` will be `undefined`.

The second passes a function reference to `app.use()` so it can call the middleware function later (which is what you want).  To pass a reference to a function, pass it without the parens at the end.

There are other examples of the same issue in your code that also need to be fixed.

Comment: perfect. Thank you

Comment: Hi jfriend00, Could you point me to the other mistakes in my code, which  you were refering to..

Comment: @Ashish - `app.use(middle.showMachineId());`.  Same issue.